# vue3+vite+elementPlus+plugin-vue-jsx+vscode occurred an error :Property 'el-button' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'

Tags: plugins, vuejs3, jsx, vite, element-plus

i want to write jsx in vue3 project,i use vite+ts+vue3+elementPlus built my project. when i wrote the follow code , vscode occurred an error,but the page run well.

```
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'
const Login = defineComponent({
    setup() {
        const count = ref(0)

        return () => (
            <div>
                <h1 onClick={() => count.value++}>{count.value}</h1>
                <el-button>hello</el-button>
            </div>
        )
    }
})

export default Login
```

[image]

Corresponding files:

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "dzmc-back",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "prepare": "husky"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@element-plus/icons-vue": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.57",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^3.1.0",
    "element-plus": "^2.5.5",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "vue": "^3.3.11",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^18.6.1",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^18.6.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.16",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.5.2",
    "@vue/babel-plugin-jsx": "^1.2.1",
    "husky": "^9.0.11",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "sass": "^1.70.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "unplugin-auto-import": "^0.17.5",
    "unplugin-vue-components": "^0.26.0",
    "vite": "^5.0.8",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.25"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./", // 解析非相对模块的基地址，默认是当前目录
    "paths": {
      //路径映射，相对于baseUrl
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue", "src/*.vue"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

vite.config.json

```json
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import { ElementPlusResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers'
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(),
  AutoImport({
    resolvers: [ElementPlusResolver()],
  }),
  Components({
    resolvers: [ElementPlusResolver()],
  }),
  vueJsx({
    transformOn: true,
    mergeProps: true
  }),
  ],
  resolve: { alias: { '@': path.resolve('./src') } },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        additionalData: '@import "./src/styles/variable.scss";',
      },
    },
    modules: {
      localsConvention: 'camelCase'
    }
  },
})
```

I think some type of file is missing or caused by related tool version upgrades

Comment: Using JSX with Vue is not very common and, most likely, whatever plugin you're using to lint Vue does not know how to handle this or is not configured correctly. I would say your question is better suited for asking directly to Vue team, on their discord channel. Most people answering Vue questions here are not part of Vue team and it's unlikely they know how to fix this (as it's not a typical Vue usage).